# Wix component condition

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

I'm trying to get a conditional component to work.

However it's not working at all so I'm stumped.

I've got the following blobs of code:

The feature is defined like this:

```
<Feature Id="MainFeature" Level="1" Title="!(loc.FEATURE.MAINFEATURE.TITLE)" 
         Description="!(loc.FEATURE.MAINFEATURE.DESCRIPTION)" Display="collapse">
      <ComponentRef Id="MainExecutable" />
      <ComponentRef Id="pmd" />
</Feature>
```

and the component is defined as

```
<Component Id="MainExecutable" Guid="*">
 <Condition><![CDATA[(&MainFeature = 3) AND NOT (!MainFeature = 3)]]></Condition>
    <File Id="MainExecutableFile" Name="SampleApp.exe" 
          Source="..\ProductBuild\sampleFile.txt" KeyPath="yes">
     <Shortcut Id="MainExecutableStartMenu" Directory="ProgramMenuDir" 
               Name="!(loc.APPNAME)" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR" 
               Icon="icon.ico" IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes"/>
     <Shortcut Id="MainExecutableDesktop" Directory="DesktopFolder" 
               Name="!(loc.APPNAME)" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR" 
               Icon="icon.ico" IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes" />
    </File>
</Component>
```

However the files are never installed!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `Component` `Condition` is not evaluated at a time that the feature states have been determined. Thus, your `Condition` will never evaulate correctly (as you've found).

However, I'm not sure you need the `Condition`. Components will only be installed when their parent Feature is set to be installed as well. It seems like your `Condition` is trying to replicate the built in behavior (but can't due to the above).

Comment: I broke this down in some detail: http://www.joyofsetup.com/2008/04/09/feature-states-in-component-conditions/

Comment: Rob - Gah! As I thought it's not doing what is expected....
The example above is very contrived to provide a very simple use case.
I want to install a short cut depending on if a component is installed or not, but I wanted to group all the short cuts together to make life easier later on.... Never mind.<br/>
@Bob - that's probably the only blog I didn't find when trying to find out why its not working! It hits the nail on the head - the documentation is misleading at best!

Comment: Yeah, sounds like a case of "don't do it that way". ;)  Hope you an find an elegant solution that still works well with the Windows Installer.

Comment: @RobMensching So what's the way of doing this then?

Comment: @DirkVollmar It isn't clear what "this" is. Probably a good idea to open a new StackOverflow question that clearly identifies what you are trying to accomplish, what you've attempted thus far, and the issue you are seeing.